# Dockerfile run scrapy crawl command in a folder

Tags: python, docker, scrapy, dockerfile

I got a scrapy spider which can be run in terminal with `scrapy crawl estate` in the tutorial folder.

How do I use the run command in Dockerfile to cd to the tutorial folder and run it?

My Dockerfile without the RUN cd:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
FROM python:3.6-onbuild
RUN  apt-get update &&apt-get upgrade -y&& apt-get install python-pip -y
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install scrapy
WORKDIR /usr/local/bin
COPY scrapy_estate/tutorial/tutorial ./
COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
COPY . .
EXPOSE 80
```

Comment: Not sure, but `CMD cd tutorial_folder && scrapy crawl $SPIDER_NAME` may work

Comment: dont CMD command need [] bracket ?

Comment: No, I use it just like this inside my project: `CMD scrapy crawl $SPIDER_NAME`.

Comment: oh ok i will try

Comment: you should use WORKDIR instead of proliferating instructions like RUN cd … && do-something, which are hard to read, troubleshoot, and maintain.

Answer (score 2):

You should set up WORKDIR, ENTRYPOINT and CMD in your docker file:

```
WORKDIR /tutorial-crawler
ENTRYPOINT ["scrapy"]
CMD []
```

Then:

```
$ docker run -it image_name list
tutorial
$ docker run -it image_name crawl tutorial
```

Comment: You really should prefer CMD to ENTRYPOINT.  (Consider the very useful `docker run --rm -it imagename sh`: setting an ENTRYPOINT breaks this.)

Comment: @DavidMaze Why? you can just override entrypoint with `--entrypoint` flag if you wish to use something else than scrapy `docker run --it --entrypoint bash imagename`

Comment: `docker run --rm --entrypoint /bin/ls myimage -l /app` is not quite the syntax you want.  Also, the common pattern I learned is that ENTRYPOINT is good for doing first-time setup and then `exec "$@"` the CMD, and if that setup is involved, the `docker run ... sh` form does the first-time setup then gives you a shell, which is incredibly useful.